# Baixa performance ao converter Blob para Bitmap

Tags: android

Eu estou usando o seguinte código :

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(blob.getBinaryStream(), null, options);
```

O problema é que isso é mais demorado do que baixar o próprio dado! Existe alguma forma mais rápida de converter , ou pelo menos, um 'BlobView' ?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é mais rápido, mas sempre utilizei esta forma:

```
 byte[] byteArray = cursor.getBlob(columIndex);
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0 ,byteArray.length);
```

E nunca tive problema com performance.